Executing a function for each row in a table
We have a Azure Digital Twin instance that contains relationships between zones & bins.
We have a dataset in Azure Data Explorer that contains data per zone
I'd like to enrich Azure Data Explorer data with the relationships from ADT.
To do that, I created a function that gets the bins for a zone from ADT - as it's only possible to do that for one zone, the zone is a parameter. The function returns an array of bins
The function looks as follows :
    .create-or-alter function with (folder='Helperfunctions') v_get_bins_for_zone(zone:string) {
let query = strcat("SELECT B FROM DIGITALTWINS Z Join B RELATED Z.ContainsBin WHERE Z.$dtId = '", zone,"'");
let binIds = evaluate azure_digital_twins_query_request("https://xxxx.api.weu.digitaltwins.azure.net", query);
let result =
binIds
| extend binId = B.Measurement.binId
| project-away B
| summarize make_list(binId);
toscalar(result);
}

This works fine in a simple case like the following
print(v_get_bins_for_zone('zone1'))

But now, I want to apply this to a table with multiple rows, so that the function is executed for each row separately
myTable
| extend result=v_get_bins_for_zone(zone)

returns
Semantic error: Unresolved reference binding: 'zone'

This is probably due to the following limitation : toscalar() can't be applied on a scenario that applies the function on each row.
Is there a workaround for this ? The function will have to be executed for each row, as the ADT query can only be executed for a single zone at the time.

I'm not entirely sure if this will work for you, but have you tried using the function as a user-defined function, instead of as a stored function? A stored function will always return a table, even though you may have toscalar() within it, but a user-defined function can return a scalar.
Try this

let v_get_bins_for_zone = (zone:string)
{
let query = strcat("SELECT B FROM DIGITALTWINS Z Join B RELATED Z.ContainsBin WHERE Z.$dtId = '", zone,"'");
let binIds = evaluate azure_digital_twins_query_request("https://xxxx.api.weu.digitaltwins.azure.net", query);
toscalar(
binIds
| extend binId = B.Measurement.binId
| project-away B
| summarize make_list(binId))
};
MyTableName
| extend result=v_get_bins_for_zone(zone)
